# Typo3 News use first image of news as hero on page outside of the extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news

I'm trying to get an image of a news in the detail view. I'd like to use it in another section of my layout. I would need it outside the news extension. So I tried:

```
7 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        7 {
           if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
           references {
              table = tx_news_domain_model_news
              fieldName = fal_media
              uid.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
           }
           sorting = datetime
           sorting.direction = descending
           as = news_images
        }
```

But unfortunately news_images is always empty, but the following returns me an url:

```
lib.newsimage = FILES
lib.newsimage {
if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
references {
    table = tx_news_domain_model_news
    uid.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
    fieldName = fal_media
}
maxItems = 1
renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
renderObj.file {
    import.data = file:current:publicUrl
}
```

}

Why is the news_images empty but the url can be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FilesProcessor, there is no `uid`-property. `data` as part of *stdWrap* has to be applied directly on `references`.

So, this should do the job:

```
7 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
7 {
   if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
   references {
      table = tx_news_domain_model_news
      fieldName = fal_media
      // vvvv
      data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      // ^^^^
   }
   sorting = datetime
   sorting.direction = descending
   as = news_images
}
```

TS reference: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/FilesProcessor.html?#filesprocessor-stdwrap-on-references

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and used the `DatabaseQueryProcessor` and the `FileProcessor`:

```
6 = database-query
6 {
    table = tx_news_domain_model_news
    pidInList = 1
    where.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
    where.wrap = uid=|

    as = news_images

    dataProcessing {
        7 = files
        7 {
            if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
            references {
                table = tx_news_domain_model_news
                fieldName = fal_media
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `pidInList` value has to be the id of your storage for news records.
With this, you get the data of your current news record and the image as `FileReference`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to select 2 correct answers. This one is working as well for my use case.